# How can I make IDA start the analysis at imagebase?

Tags: ida, memory

I noticed that despite the imagebase for win32 executables be 0x400000, Ida Pro only starts the analysis at 0x401000. What is before that and how can I change IDA's settings to start the analysis at the imagebase? Thank you.

Comment: Typically there is nothing before that. You might as well ask "what's before `400000h`". The code *section* starts at +1000h.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PE executables start with a header block that consists of a little DOS exe stub (with its own little header), a structure called [IMAGE_NT_HEADERS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680336%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and a section table. A normal PE has no 32-bit/64-bit executable code there, so IDA doesn't load the header block unless you check "**manual load**".

Relevant resources:

- Microsoft's [PE COFF specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx) (currently at version 8.3)
- Matt Pietrek's classic [Peering Inside the PE: A Tour of the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms809762.aspx)
- its sequel [An In-Depth Look into the Win32 Portable Executable File Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx)
- ReversingLabs' [Undocumented PECOFF](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Vuksan/BH_US_11_VuksanPericin_PECOFF_WP.pdf)